# pyodbc.DataError: ('22003', '[22003] [Oracle][ODBC]Numeric value out of range. (0) (SQLGet Data)') with a LONG field type

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pyodbc

I'm a newbie in pyodbc and I searched a lot but I didn't find the answer I was looking for. I have a piece of code written in python that I have to debug. I can't use another module instead of pyodbc. Here's my problem :
I take the columns from a table like this :

```
col_list = self.connection.cursor().columns(table=tabspec["name"], schema=tabspec["schema"])
```

then I loop on them to have the name of each column :

```
for c in col_list:
            colspec["column_name"] = c.column_name...
```

The problem is, in the table, there's a column which type is LONG() and at that specific one, I have the following error :

```
    pyodbc.DataError: ('22003', '[22003] [Oracle][ODBC]Numeric value out of range. (0) (SQLGetData)')
```

I cannot change the database so I have to find a solution in my python code. Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create new objects in your database?

Comment: I cannot change in any way the database. My program selects the columns to make some tests on them but it doesn't make any changes on the database.

Comment: Do you get the same error with cx_Oracle?

Comment: I don't know what is cx_Oracle.

Comment: I edited my question : I have to use pyodbc since I'm debugging an already written piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it seems like bug in `pyodbc`. I can reproduce it on my Oracle database by running:

```
db = pyodbc.connect('DSN=test;PWD=passwd')
c = db.cursor()
col_list = c.columns(table="PLAN_TABLE")
for col in col_list:
    print(col)
```

I checked that `PLAN_TABLE` has one column of `LONG` type.

Other libraries I use: `odbc` and `cx_Oracle` do not have `columns()` method so they cannot be used.

I think that you can fill bug report and find workaround. To find workaround you will have to tell us what are you going to do: report schema, exchange data etc. Maybe you can use other library like `cx_Oracle` or you can use other `pyodbc` method to find requested information.

If all you need is column names of selected table then you can query Oracle metadata:

```
TBL_COLUMNS_SQL = """SELECT column_name
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE LOWER(table_name)=LOWER('%s')
"""

def get_columns(cursor, tbl_name):
    result = []
    cursor.execute(TBL_COLUMNS_SQL % (tbl_name))
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        result.append(row[0])
    return result
```

For more metadata information like types, size, default value etc refer to my tool that creates report of Oracle database: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576534-dump-oracle-db-schema-to-text/

Comment: Is there any other method in pyodbc that gives me the columns of a table? And in my code, I just do a check between two databases (a reference and another) to find out if any changes have occurred between them. So I'm just comparing the content of each column in each database.

Comment: You can query metadata. See my code that reports Oracle metadata: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576534-dump-oracle-db-schema-to-text/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I cannot change anything in the code except debugging it. Is there anyway I can enlarge the buffer in witch the columns are so the LONG value can fit in?

Comment: In my edited answer I added `pyodbc` code that reads Oracle metadata and return column names.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works but I can't change the code too much. So the only solution I found is to ignore the columns with LONG value.